# Read only text boxes on customer details

Tags: c#, html, readonly

I am trying to show customer details on a webiste which are read-only to one customer type but amendable to another. How can I add this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on user, you can add `readonly` attribute to textboxes.

Suppose you want textboxes to be readonly for a particular user, then,

```
txtName.Attributes.Add("readonly","readonly");
```

For other users, dont add this line.

Also, `readonly` will prevent user from editing data despite having cursor in that field. So no need to worry about editing.

Comment: Thank you! Is there anyway to also stop the cursor blinking in the textbox i.e. the user cannot focus on it?

Comment: You can add `disabled` attribute instead. Please accept as answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

So there is a [TextBox.ReadOnly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.readonly(v=vs.110).aspx) property which you can set for the aspx controls. For the input you would just need to put [readonly](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_readonly.asp) as an attribute

eg:

```
  <input readonly name="txtName" type="text" id="txtName" runat="server" onchange="ProfileIsDirty()" ToolTip="Name" class="form-control height-fix no-border-bottom"  placeholder="NAME" MaxLength="200"/>
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there anyway to also stop the cursor blinking in the textbox i.e. the user cannot focus on it?

Comment: for the asp.net controls I think that Enabled=False would work but I don't have a project on me that I could try that on.

Answer (score 1):

```
<form action="demo_form.asp">
  Country: <input type="text" name="country" value="Norway" disabled><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

"disabled" attribute prevents user interaction